# Powershell script to run on all computers in domain - wait until computer is online

Tags: powershell, active-directory, offline

I have pieced together the following PowerShell script that deletes a file from the public desktop of every machine in an OU on our domain, and then copies a replacement file back to replace it. It works well, except for the machines that are offline. What would be the best way to have the script run on a machine once it comes online? My best guess is to have it put any offline machine in a list, then re-run a few hours later for the computers on that list. Is there a better way?

```
$DESTINATION = "c$\Users\Public\Desktop"
$REMOVE = "ComputerName"
$strFilter = "computer"

$objDomain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry

$objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$objSearcher.SearchRoot = "LDAP://OU=MyOU,DC=Domain,DC=com"
$objSearcher.SearchScope = "Subtree" 
$objSearcher.PageSize = 1000 

$objSearcher.Filter = "(objectCategory=$strFilter)"
$colResults = $objSearcher.FindAll()

foreach ($i in $colResults) 
    {
        $objComputer = $i.GetDirectoryEntry()
        $REMOVE = $objComputer.Name
        #Ping system to see if it's on
        $rtn = Test-Connection -CN $REMOVE -Count 2 -BufferSize 16 -Quiet

        IF($rtn -match 'True') {

            Remove-Item "\\$REMOVE\$DESTINATION\SparksNET.url" -Recurse
            Copy-Item "\\spd3\PD IT stuff\Software\Desktop Icons\mySparks.website" "\\$REMOVE\$DESTINATION"   
        }
        ELSE { 
        }

    }
```

Comment: Why not just do it as a group policy? It's easy to update a file via that route.

Comment: Partially because I want to learn PowerShell, partially because I don't know what that GPO is off-hand. lol. Mostly cuz I want to learn powershell though.

Comment: Part of learning a tool is learning when it's not the most appropriate solution. @MarcB is correct, this would be much better done via GPO. Not trying to discourage you, but using GPO would eliminate the problem you're encountering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everyone is 100% correct, you should do this through GPO. However, if you crazily want to do it through PowerShell, you *could* do it the way I have outlined below. I threw your code into it - so it might be a tad messy.

Start off by pulling in the list of PC's and then send them all off to a job...

```
if(Test-Path "c:\LogPath"){
}else {
mkdir "c:\LogPath"
}

$time=Get-Date -Format s
$date=Get-Date -Format F

"LOG FILE CREATED - $date" | Add-Content $log

$objDomain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry

$objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$objSearcher.SearchRoot = "LDAP://OU=MyOU,DC=Domain,DC=com"
$objSearcher.SearchScope = "Subtree" 
$objSearcher.PageSize = 1000 

$objSearcher.Filter = "(objectCategory=$strFilter)"
$colResults = $objSearcher.FindAll()

foreach($Obj in $colResults){ 

        $objComputer = $Obj.GetDirectoryEntry()
        $remotePC = $objComputer.Name


    #Imports all functions used in script
    . "C:\PathToYourJobScript.ps1"



    #Creating Jobs
    $jobs = (get-job -state running | Measure-Object).count 
        Get-job -State Completed | Remove-Job
            while($jobs -ge 5)    
               {
                  #get currently running jobs after restart

            get-job -state running | %{write-host $_.PSBeginTime} | ?{($_.PSBeginTime - $(Get-Date)).Minutes -gt 10} | Remove-Job
            Write-host "Currently running maximum threads at: $jobs `n Sleeping 5 seconds"  -ForegroundColor DarkYellow

            start-sleep -seconds 5

            $jobs = (get-job -state running | Measure-Object).count 
               }

    Write-host "`t`tCreating Thread for $remotePC" -ForegroundColor Yellow

    start-job $DeleteFile -ArgumentList $remotePC -Name $remotePC 
    Receive-Job $remotePC

    "$remotePC; Starting Job at; $time" | Add-Content $log
    }
```

In your actual job script PS1, wrap your code above into one function

```
$DeleteFile={Param(
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$remotePC
    ) 
<#
.SYNOPSIS 

.DESCRIPTION 

.NOTES 


#>

##Globals
$DESTINATION = "c$\Users\Public\Desktop"
$REMOVE = "ComputerName"
$strFilter = "computer"

        #Ping system to see if it's on


        if(Test-Connection -ComputerName $remotePC -Count 2  -BufferSize 16 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){
            Remove-Item "\\$REMOVE\$DESTINATION\SparksNET.url" -Recurse
            Copy-Item "\\spd3\PD IT stuff\Software\Desktop Icons\mySparks.website" "\\$REMOVE\$DESTINATION" 
            "$remotePC; Removal Complete; $time" | Add-Content $log  
            }
            ELSE 
            { 
            do {Start-Sleep -Seconds 300;  "$remotePC; Ping Fail; $time" | Add-Content $log}
            until (Test-Connection -ComputerName $remotePC -Count 2  -BufferSize 16 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
            Remove-Item "\\$REMOVE\$DESTINATION\SparksNET.url" -Recurse
            Copy-Item "\\spd3\PD IT stuff\Software\Desktop Icons\mySparks.website" "\\$REMOVE\$DESTINATION" 
            "$remotePC; Removal Complete; $time" | Add-Content $log  
            }
}
```

This will check every 5 minutes if the PC is online and wait until it gets a response to proceed. Once an item is tossed into a job, you loose site of its progress and would want to log accordingly so you know its position.

Comment: Awesome. I think I will take your advice and use a GPO to accomplish this. I have one question though: If I do use a GPO, won't that add to the GPO processing time of every computer, even when they have already completed the task? I am trying to limit the number of GPOs I have to the ones that are absolutely necessary.

Comment: I am not well versed in GPO but I do know the trouble in running scripts vs offline machines. If you just want to one shot it, and not too many would be offline, then PowerShell is probably OK. If you have a lot of machines, and a lot will be offline you would want to look into GPO or SCCM for removal. As far as processing time, you would be removing the GPO eventually anyway.

Comment: @MattDryden So I just spoke with our GPO guy - the impact is extremely minimal. If you had machines out in the field connecting it may take a little longer, but it is so short to be unnoticeable. It should be tied into an already created object, if one exists for that group.

Comment: Great info. Thanks Robert! I pushed it with a GPO and it's worked great. I'll hang onto this script for future use though. Thanks!